# Как исправить код, чтобы была пересылка сообщения, а не ее копия (чтобы можно было перейти на страницу человека)

Tags: python-telegram-bot

```
import telebot
# pip install pytelegrambotapi
token = 'TOKEN Вашего бота'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
chat_id = 'Ваш chat_id' # Например chat_id = '223344'
# Telegram bot: Get My Id
 
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def main(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Привет, это бот!")
 
 
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_message(message):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message.text)
 
 
bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
bot.forward_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message.text)
```